# Can I revoke a Vote To Close if the questioner fixed the problem?

Tags: support

This [question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4935/latex-vs-word-vs-etc) was originally a poll. I said I would VTC if it weren't fixed, gave it a day, voted to close, and then the poster fixed it. Is there a way to remove my vote to close now that it's been fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to do that.  As long as the question no longer meets close criteria other people won't vote to close it and the vote to close will harmlessly expire shortly.  If it is already closed, vote to re-open it.

Comment: This has come up several times on meta.SO, but they've never added support for cancelling a close vote. Partially because, as justkt says, you can get along pretty well without it.

Answer (score 3):

I just retracted my close vote on this question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I additionally found out that you can retract a close vote if you do it within I think an hour of casting it. But it must be like the five-minute edit window on comments — you only have so long to do it, and then the system locks you out.